# how to unbind focus.autocomplete that replace default val

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Have an issue with jquery autocomplete, focus function

After i type something in the input, the autocomplete dropdown a list of suggestion options.
but when selecting something in that 'dropdown options' with the keyboard or mouse hover, it triggers change in the default input value.

how do i unbind this action, i want it to remain the default val() until the option is selected.

```
.autocomplete({
   options?
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? an option was selected.

Comment: edited, the suggestion option that dropdown after you type, if you focus on one of these options, it replaces the default.value, which is not what i want

Comment: There are actually quite a few autocomplete plugins, some even use the same method name, so linking to the plugin would probably help. Also, did you check the plugins website yourself to see if there was an easy answer to this.

Comment: @adeneo. it's probably the jQuery-UI plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `preventDefault` on the event supplied to the `focus` handler:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    /*...*/
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/qbETA/

Comment: OMG, this took me 4 hours!!!! thank you so so much, i Almost got encouraged to overwrite the ui.menu functions